# CFReadStreamClientCallBack in Background thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In  my app i open a server on the WiFi for sharing files and upload files from web browser to the app.
I have a problem that it work on the main thread(the UI thread) and it make a lot of problems, there is a way to make this code work in the background instead?

This is the code:

I make read stream non-blocking with this method:

```
if (!CFReadStreamSetClient (theReadStream,
    kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable | kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred | kCFStreamEventEndEncountered | kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted,
    (CFReadStreamClientCallBack)&MyCFReadStreamCallback,
    (CFStreamClientContext *)(&theContext) ))
{
    NSError *err = [self getStreamError];

    NSLog (@"AsyncSocket %p couldn't attach read stream to run-loop,", self);
    NSLog (@"Error: %@", err);

    if (errPtr) *errPtr = err;
    return NO;
}
```

and it call this method:

```
    static void MyCFReadStreamCallback (CFReadStreamRef stream, CFStreamEventType type, void *pInfo)
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        AsyncSocket *socket = [[(AsyncSocket *)pInfo retain] autorelease];
        [socket doCFReadStreamCallback:type forStream:stream];

        [pool release];
    }
```

this is the source code i use:
http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just spawn a background thread with the code like this:

```
bgThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(threadMain) object:nil];
[bgThread start];
```

and start your server listener in 'threadMain' method.

read more about multithreading in [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading)